# Is there a way to refactor an angular 2 component?

Tags: angular

When you build a SPA you start with an idea and frequently you decide to rename everything because you rethink a part of the application.

I have tried several IDEs (sublime, atom and visual studio code) but none of them seem to allow you to **refactor a component** (as you do with a java class in eclipse for instance). Is there any IDE or plugin with that functionality?

I would **dream** with a black magic option in @angular/cli such as

`ng refactor my-component new-fancier-name`

Comment: VS Code actually does allow this. Highlight the item you want to rename, and press F2, or right click and `rename symbol`

Comment: with VS code you can refactor the name of the class but not the selector, styles and filenames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webstorm offers that feature

[image]

as well as drag and drop a component to another place reroutes any references it detects